# Drupal Webform vs Content Type vs Custom Module ? Which way should I go with?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cck, drupal-webform

I am trying to build a "small system" through which the register users (organizations) will be able to fill a form (Questionnaire). The data that the users have filled should appear on a chart for the administrator to analyze. The user can only submit the data just once but they can update it.

The problem that I have faced is the fact that Webform module is not integrated with views. Content type doesn't truly reflect the structure since the content type always contain a title .

Am I only left with the option of building a custom module? Any references for something similar ....

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the Profile 2 module for Drupal 7: http://drupal.org/project/profile2

You can integrate profile fields with Views as it says under its features section on the description page: "You may use Views and/or the Search API to provide listings or searches for profiles."